# What is the index of $H$ in $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let A:=$\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. Let $G$ be the group of bijections (as a set) of $A$, the multiplication being composition. Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ consisting of those bijections $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(x+2)=\sigma(x)+2$ for all $x$ in $A$. What is the index of $H$ in $G$?

My attempt:
The number of bijections (as a set) of $A$ are $= 720$. This follows beacause if  $1 \mapsto x$ , then $x$ has 6 possibilities, $2 \mapsto y$, then $y$ has 5 possibilities and so on.

Now we need to find the index of $H$ in $G$. Clearly, the identity map from set A to itself is an element of subgroup $H$. But I am finding it difficult on how to find elements of H s.t. $\sigma(x+2)=\sigma(x)+2$.Please tell me how to proceed and explicitly find those maps.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you know what $\sigma$ does to $0+6\mathbb{Z}$, you also know what it does to $2+6\mathbb{Z}$ and to $4+6\mathbb{Z}$. Once you know what happens to $1+6\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: I assume in $\sigma(x+2) = \sigma(x) +2$ both additions are meant modulo 6?

Comment: @mick i also believe the same

Comment: May I please know, why my question has been downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you know that:
$1\mapsto x$, then you can deduce using $$\sigma(x+2)=\sigma(x)+2$$ that $3\mapsto x+2$ and $5\mapsto x+4$. Observe that this is all you can deduce from knowing $\sigma(1)$. Similarly, if $2\mapsto y$, then $4\mapsto y+2$, and $6\mapsto y+4$. Hence, knowing $\sigma(1)$ and $\sigma(2)$ you can determines $\sigma$. Note that there are $6$ options for $\sigma(1)$, and once $\sigma(1)$ is determined, it determines $\sigma(3),\sigma(5)$; thus, there only remain $3$ options for where to send $\sigma(2)$. Hence, there are $18$ such permutations. Hence the index will be $\frac{720}{18}=40$

Comment: i believe it won't be difficult to explicitly state $\sigma$, it will just be depend on values of $x$ and $y$